# How can i place square Feature Image withing the body of post aligned top left or top right in wordpress?

Tags: thumbnails

I want to place a featured image of my news website below the title inside the post aligned right or left top, right (as you see in any news webpage) now it is placed below the title, but it is big, and it is before the post. you can check any post of my blog at `HTTP://www.hindustantimes.xyz`

Someone, please help me with any CSS code considering me a noob in coding.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the layout that you are finding? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/

If yes, then you may refer the code inside :D

For Picture/Image resolution, try adjusting `width` and `height`